# Final output don't return correct result in my Python multiprocessing code

Tags: python, queue, multiprocessing

I'm learning multiprocessing of Python, I want to use it to resolve my problem.

My problem(already simplified):

I have a list number_list - `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, I want to start 2+
processes(only start 1 in my code below), each process will validate
the items in the list, if the item match my condition, then process
will append it to another new_number_list.

Now my problem is finally new_number_list is always [ ].

Can someone help check? Thanks!

See my code:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from multiprocessing import Queue
from multiprocessing import Pool
import multiprocessing

number_list = range(10)
new_number_list = []

def add_new_number_list(number, lock):
    lock.acquire()
    print "%s is added." % str(number)
    global new_number_list
    new_number_list.append(number)
    print new_number_list
    lock.release()

def check(number_list_q, lock):
    while True:
        if not number_list_q.empty():
            value = number_list_q.get()
            if 0 == value % 3:
                add_new_number_list(value, lock)
        else:
            break

def main():
    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    number_list_q = manager.Queue()
    for i in number_list:
        number_list_q.put(i)
    lock = manager.Lock()
    p = Pool()
    p1 = p.apply_async(check, args=(number_list_q, lock))
    p.close()
    p.join()
    print new_number_list
    print 'Done.'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can processes share list between each other in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9005117/how-can-processes-share-list-between-each-other-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed your code by returning a result from the process and [using apply_async's result](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers), which is available by using `result.get()`. [Read how to use it further](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult).

Note that the **spawned** process (`fork`ed from main) has a copy of `new_number_list` in it's memory, but when it's written to, it's copied and the result isn't visible on the main process's memory. This happens due to [copy-on-write](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write) optimization.

You could have the same memory available using `multithreading`, but it won't spawn any new processes, and is slower in some use-cases.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from multiprocessing import Process
from multiprocessing import Queue
from multiprocessing import Pool
import multiprocessing

number_list = range(10)
new_number_list = []

def add_new_number_list(number, lock):
    lock.acquire()
    print "%s is added." % str(number)
    global new_number_list
    new_number_list.append(number)
    print new_number_list
    lock.release()

def check(number_list_q, lock):
    while True:
        if not number_list_q.empty():
            value = number_list_q.get()
            if 0 == value % 3:
                add_new_number_list(value, lock)
        else:
            break
    return new_number_list

def main():
    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    number_list_q = manager.Queue()
    for i in number_list:
        number_list_q.put(i)
    lock = manager.Lock()
    p = Pool()
    # return the apply_async result
    new_number_list = p.apply_async(check, args=(number_list_q, lock))
    p.close()
    p.join()
    # get the result (it's ready since we 'join'-ed)
    print new_number_list.get()
    print 'Done.'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Appreciate your help so much!